# Rails and Stripe Payments

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, stripe-payments

Having trouble in the early stages of setting up Rails and Stripe and I'm following this Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe

Trying to get the form to be detected by the javascript (coffeescript) on submit but it just submits to the create action and ignores the javascript.

Here is my coffeescript (borrowed from Railcasts):

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  subscription.setupForm()

  subscription =
    setupForm: ->
      $('#new_subscription').submit ->
        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
        subscription.processCard()
        false

    processCard: ->
      card = 
        number: $('#card_number').val()
        cvc: $('#card_code').val()
        expMonth: $('#card_month').val()
        expYear: $('#card_year').val()
      Stripe.createToken(card, subscription.handleStripeResponse)

    handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
      if status == 200
        alert(response.id)
      else
        alert(response.error.message)
```

I have generated my form like this but not too sure about this part...

```
<%= form_tag accounts_path, {:id => 'new_subscription'} do %>
```

this creates:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/accounts" id="new_subscription" method="post">
```

notice that it does have the right id. I had to set the ID specifically even though in Ryan's tutorials he did not seem to have to.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: sorry - edited the question to now contain the link

Answer (score 1):

I think you should watch your JavaScript console for errors. I think you're getting a JavaScript TypeError right here:

```
subscription.setupForm()
```

Both JavaScript and CoffeeScript will hoist a variable *declaration* to the top of the scope but neither will hoist the *definition*. For example, this CoffeeScript:

```
pancakes.m()
pancakes =
    m: -> console.log('pancakes')
```

becomes this JavaScript:

```
var pancakes;

pancakes.m();

pancakes = {
  m: function() {
    return console.log('pancakes');
  }
};
```

so `pancakes` exists when I say `pancakes.m()` but `pancakes` is still `undefined` at the point and so it has no `m` method until later when we assign it a value. [**Demo**](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3apancakes.m%28%29%0Apancakes%20=%0A%20%20%20%20m%3a%20-%3E%20console.log%28%27pancakes%27%29)

Applying that to your code tells us that `subscription` is `undefined` when you try to `subscription.setupForm()`. Try putting things in the right order:

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  subscription = ...
  subscription.setupForm()
```

---

If you look at the Railscast code, you'll see that the structure is like this:

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  subscription.setupForm()

subscription = #...
```

Notice that `subscription` is defined outside the `jQuery ->` function? `jQuery ->` delays execution until after the page is loaded but by that time, the `subscription = ...` part of the code will have been executed already and `subscription` will have a non-`undefined` value.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - as it was a Railscast I would have thought it would work - in the end I decided to use "raw" javascript and it's working nicely.

Comment: The Railscast code *does* work, you just accidentally changed the indentation (and hence structure since this is CoffeeScript) when you copied the code.

Comment: That's a copy and paste issue though! Appreciate the help anyway.